# код написанный на питоне нужно добавить в Андройд приложение которое написано на джаве

Tags: java, android, python

Всем доброго времени суток, столкнулся с проблемой,есть датчик который передает данные в телефон по средству юсб,код андройд приложение написано на джаве,а вот драйвер на датчик написан на питоне. Как быть в такой ситуации кто подскажет? Есть ли возможность добавить классы написанные на питоне в проект,пропустить байт код через джаву, что бы дружили с друг другом и не было проблем?Или есть библиотеки которые позволяют дружить двум языкам в одном приложении андройда?Очень нужна помочь . Да прибудет с Вами сила))))

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вообще нужно здесь интегрировать Python и Java?

Данные идут по USB-кабелю. Значит, ваша задача - **через Java-код получить данные с USB-порта**. Ищите на Android Development нужный вам Android-интерфейс.